# Mark specific points in a time series plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have 2 tsibble objects, one being (atsibble) a time series plot:

```
structure(list(a = c(-0.126892035380323, -1.06715037063515, -1.60787487653968, 
-0.430590456130063, -1.05521361336675, -0.414278601625663, 0.654581233587062, 
-0.249577748546152, 1.40972713971785, 2.09474379990156, -0.715632058670565, 
-0.00843181389540247, 0.766631408555856, 2.15115002137533, 0.379725018747415, 
1.69721621405787, -1.70583648313058, 0.680442145897233, 0.761783303977843, 
-0.553447181216436, -0.258042475066994, -0.139402110427028, -1.12226126127863, 
0.20450563691496, 0.467800894994345, 1.66589450712862, -0.944175113659552, 
-0.922645506459805, -1.56029364483165, 0.227935249754017, 2.77082355807429, 
-0.538253797945127, -0.432943384383603, -1.86459168062383, -0.769132864176306, 
0.582411820024063, 1.26413580895661, 1.96284160061773, -0.901140768083693, 
0.816406048274658, 0.737583569742308, 0.201766885025892, -1.47727187469498, 
-0.749268566264527, -0.17205509796403, 0.409054411236262, 1.87951650910632, 
1.61615348619591, 1.13556525217184, -0.620166421335986, -0.435639092396967, 
-0.0222695889281877, 1.20227294397974, -0.570755699942241, -0.339700970804648, 
0.0775732171772367, -1.97531382736573, 0.397973838394827, -1.42840556836806, 
-0.331533816579742, -0.316229809413294, -0.202058443204902, 0.745932924192128, 
-1.11826633092722, 0.823946205739166, 0.487264340924317, 0.39342590504187, 
0.242227063059577, -0.413081101187916, -2.45416198828715, 0.698888462687966, 
-0.0129038187399903, -0.430140168296895, -2.42533435187924, -0.56791861893217, 
0.106339696676824, -0.155801042802037, -0.110220406289553, 0.0597586101706477, 
0.00591590072864023, -1.16070004138283, -0.246453499690402, 0.824368213004575, 
0.461186701360489, -0.34563112002606, -0.19224336493559, 0.648736129969731, 
-0.411971228614746, 0.357006835412275, -0.106678747291236, 3.02616715624053, 
0.602431536781862, -0.647308873694011, -2.02383682574903, -0.189813597182051, 
0.463275862179929, 0.825994798657101, -1.26559481427883, 1.37436564351133, 
0.425375764782639, 1.36164210999818, -0.141258748380729, 0.989298568502628, 
-0.925899046880345, 0.310819177596288, -0.0654467057958754, -1.72429980290691, 
-0.169763588952388, -0.610635325666202, 0.318923654286985, 0.695450445610489, 
0.327365893824309, -0.162972033829379, -0.907546907313167, 2.26186837377977, 
-0.100701247672589, 0.0242335761864823, 1.12891580873337, 0.219437502229037, 
1.08303878786712, -0.888065004393974), Date = structure(c(15340, 
15341, 15342, 15343, 15344, 15345, 15346, 15347, 15348, 15349, 
15350, 15351, 15352, 15353, 15354, 15355, 15356, 15357, 15358, 
15359, 15360, 15361, 15362, 15363, 15364, 15365, 15366, 15367, 
15368, 15369, 15370, 15371, 15372, 15373, 15374, 15375, 15376, 
15377, 15378, 15379, 15380, 15381, 15382, 15383, 15384, 15385, 
15386, 15387, 15388, 15389, 15390, 15391, 15392, 15393, 15394, 
15395, 15396, 15397, 15398, 15399, 15400, 15401, 15402, 15403, 
15404, 15405, 15406, 15407, 15408, 15409, 15410, 15411, 15412, 
15413, 15414, 15415, 15416, 15417, 15418, 15419, 15420, 15421, 
15422, 15423, 15424, 15425, 15426, 15427, 15428, 15429, 15430, 
15431, 15432, 15433, 15434, 15435, 15436, 15437, 15438, 15439, 
15440, 15441, 15442, 15443, 15444, 15445, 15446, 15447, 15448, 
15449, 15450, 15451, 15452, 15453, 15454, 15455, 15456, 15457, 
15458, 15459, 15460), class = "Date")), row.names = c(NA, -121L
), key = structure(list(.rows = structure(list(1:121), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
"vctrs_vctr", "list"))), row.names = c(NA, -1L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame")), index = structure("Date", ordered = TRUE), index2 = "Date", interval = structure(list(
    year = 0, quarter = 0, month = 0, week = 0, day = 1, hour = 0, 
    minute = 0, second = 0, millisecond = 0, microsecond = 0, 
    nanosecond = 0, unit = 0), .regular = TRUE, class = c("interval", 
"vctrs_rcrd", "vctrs_vctr")), class = c("tbl_ts", "tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))

atsibble %>%
  autoplot() +
  xlab(NULL) + 
  ylab("Measures")+
  theme_bw() +
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(),panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),panel.border = element_blank(), axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"),
        axis.text.x = element_text(size = 8.5))
```

I need to plot the values of the second tsibble object (btsibble) in the previous plot, marking the points with red dots, as the following picture

```
structure(list(b = c(0.206962033375623, 0.891419914418517, 1.88103143380816, 
-1.69760027628251, -0.251005421209725, 1.9684360324324, -1.24660538607931, 
0.619690692026719, 0.934452561665273, 0.625090658921708, -0.442361211846564, 
-0.816005795115502, -1.14101027379553, 0.00485717434024728, -0.774768252728837, 
-0.520123708879298, 0.191345063070901, -0.0816920801430231), 
    Date = structure(c(15340, 15347, 15354, 15361, 15368, 15375, 
    15382, 15389, 15396, 15403, 15410, 15417, 15424, 15431, 15438, 
    15445, 15452, 15459), class = "Date")), row.names = c(NA, 
-18L), key = structure(list(.rows = structure(list(1:18), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
"vctrs_vctr", "list"))), row.names = c(NA, -1L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame")), index = structure("Date", ordered = TRUE), index2 = "Date", interval = structure(list(
    year = 0, quarter = 0, month = 0, week = 0, day = 7, hour = 0, 
    minute = 0, second = 0, millisecond = 0, microsecond = 0, 
    nanosecond = 0, unit = 0), .regular = TRUE, class = c("interval", 
"vctrs_rcrd", "vctrs_vctr")), class = c("tbl_ts", "tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))
```

[image]

I tried with geom_point but it didn't work. Tried the gghighlight package but gave me an error. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to redefine the data source in the call to `geom_point()` since you are referring to a different dataset.

```
atsibble %>%
   ggplot(aes(x=Date, y=a)) +
   geom_line() +
   xlab(NULL) + 
   ylab("Measures")+
   geom_point(data=btsibble, aes(x=Date, y=b), col="red") +
   theme_bw() +
   theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(),panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),panel.border = element_blank(), axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"),
         axis.text.x = element_text(size = 8.5))
```

[image]